# DCG prolog testing several sentences

Tags: prolog, dcg

If I have the below piece of code, how would I make it produce `Answer= 5 and Answer2= 10?`. I run the goal `?- test(Data),lpsolve(Data, [Answer1,Answer2]).`

```
    :-use_module(library(clpfd)).
    test([the, variable, X, is, five,fullstop,
          the,variable, Y, is, ten, fullstop]).
    lpsolve(Data, [Answer,Answer2]):- sentence(Answer, Data,[]).

    sentence(X) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(X).
    nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
    verbphrase(X) --> [X], [is], [five],[fullstop], {X = 5}.

    sentence(Y) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(Y).
    nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
    verbphrase(Y) --> [Y], [is], [ten],[fullstop], {Y = 10}.
```

Example of a program that actually runs and is closely related is the following:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
test([the, variable, X, is, five,fullstop]).
lpsolve(Data, Answer):- sentence(Answer, Data,[]).

sentence(X) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(X).
nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
verbphrase(X) --> [X], [is], [five],[fullstop], {X = 5}.
```

I have just one sentence to test and the goal succeeds as shown below.

```
 ?- test(Data),lpsolve(Data, Answer).
    Data = [the, variable, 5, is, five],
    Answer = 5.
```

**EDIT**

I try the following as per the first comment:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

test([the, variable, x, is, five,fullstop,
      the,variable, y, is, ten, fullstop]).
lpsolve(Data, Answer):- sentence(Answer, Data,[]).

sentence(X) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(X).
nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
verbphrase(X) --> [x], [is], [five],[fullstop], {X = 5}. 
verbphrase(Y) --> [y], [is], [ten],[fullstop], {Y = 10}.
```

I get the following:

```
-? test(Data),lpsolve(Data, Answer).
false.
```

Comment: This is the wrong way about it. Keep just one `Answer` variable, just like the original. Prolog will find each solution for `Answer`. If  you really need a list, use `findall/3` for that. Also, you can get rid of the redundant `nounphrase --> [the], [variable].` and `sentence(Y) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(Y).`. These rules already exist and there is no need to have them again. In other words, the only difference between your code and the original should be an extra `verbphrase(X) --> ...` clause to handle the different number.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am not sure if that is what you meant. It results in false

Comment: Actually, it only results in 5, not false. I left out one thing: you also need `test([
      the,variable, y, is, ten, fullstop]).` in addition to `test([the, variable, x, is, five,fullstop]).`

Comment: Is there a way to supply all sentences followed by say full stop? I ask this because I intend to input related sentences to solve some constraints. Calling one goal at a time might not work.

Comment: Also, my code above under the title edit gives false. I am not sure if you used exactly the same code.

Comment: I'm a little annoyed that you are parsing a determiner and an adjective as a noun phrase, and a bare noun against a verb as your verb phrase. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but I feel your DCG is broken down in completely strange ways and you may benefit from seeing another way to arrange it.

You have a list of variable bindings, so you should already be thinking in terms of obtaining a list of results rather than a single result:

```
sentences([S|Ss]) --> sentence(S), sentences(Ss).
sentences([]) --> [].
```

What is a sentence? It is a noun phrase and a verb phrase, in your simple system. But you have broken the noun and verb phrases apart incorrectly for English, where a sentence like "The variable X is 5" should be broken into a noun phrase subject "The variable X" and a verb phrase "is 5". Ideally, the verb phrase should be decomposed further into a verb another noun phrase, but we're ignoring that detail for now. I am looking for the verb "is" to relate it to the Prolog predicate `=/2`, and handling `fullstop` here:

```
sentence(N1=N2) --> nounphrase(N1), verbphrase(is, N2), [fullstop].
```

OK, so now we need your noun phrase:

```
nounphrase(N) --> [the, variable, N].
```

And your verb phrase:

```
verbphrase(is, V) --> [is], value(V).
```

I'm only handling the two decodings and I'm doing it implicitly in the DCG definition:

```
value(5) --> [five].
value(10) --> [ten].
```

You'll find this works for the use case you've defined above:

```
?- phrase(sentences(S), [the,variable,X,is,five,fullstop,the,variable,Y,is,ten,fullstop]).
  S = [X=5, Y=10] ;
  false.
```