# DCG prolog returning multiple variable answers

Tags: prolog, dcg

Consider the following code snippet:
The task is to get variables and their values from sentences of the form `[the, variable, x, is, five,fullstop]`. The varaible and values in such a sentence would be `X=5` or `[X,5]`.

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

test([the, variable, x, is, five,fullstop, the,variable, y, is, five, fullstop
    ]).

lpsolve(Data, Answers):- lpsolve( [], Variables, Answers, Data, [] ).
                        % labeling( [], Variables ).

lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables, Answers, Data, Remainder ) :- sentence(Answers, Data,Remainder).
lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables, Answers, Data, Remainder ) :- sentence(Answers, Data,SentencesInBetween),
                                    lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables,Answers,SentencesInBetween, Remainder).

sentence(X) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(X).
nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
verbphrase(X) --> [x], [is], [five],[fullstop], {X = 5}. 
verbphrase(Y) --> [y], [is], [five],[fullstop], {Y = 5}.
```

If I run:

```
?- test(Data),lpsolve(Data, Answer).
Data = [the, variable, x, is, five, fullstop, the, variable, y|...],
Answer = 5
```

But imagine a case where X and Y are different:

:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

```
test([the, variable, x, is, five,fullstop, the,variable, y, is, ten, fullstop
    ]).

lpsolve(Data, Answers):- lpsolve( [], Variables, Answers, Data, [] ).
                        % labeling( [], Variables ).

lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables, Answers, Data, Remainder ) :- sentence(Answers, Data,Remainder).
lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables, Answers, Data, Remainder ) :- sentence(Answers, Data,SentencesInBetween),
                                    lpsolve( PreviousVariables, CurrentVariables,Answers,SentencesInBetween, Remainder).

sentence(X) --> nounphrase, verbphrase(X).
nounphrase --> [the], [variable].
verbphrase(X) --> [x], [is], [five],[fullstop], {X = 5}. 
verbphrase(Y) --> [y], [is], [ten],[fullstop], {Y = 10}.
```

The result would be:

```
?- test(Data),lpsolve(Data, Answer).
Data = [the, variable, x, is, five, fullstop, the, variable, y|...],
false.
```

Of course, it tries to evaluate `5=10?` and fails. So the question is how to collect separate Variables and their values into `Answer`.

The answer would look something like:

```
?- test(Data),lpsolve(Data, Answer).
    Data = [the, variable, x, is, five, fullstop, the, variable, y|...],
    X= 5, Y=10.
```

**Also, how can I collect the variables X and Y into PreviousVariables and CurrentVariables? When I encounter a new sentence in my inputdata(a new sentence starts after fullstop. see input data format), I should update the PreviousVariables from say `[[X,5]]` to CurrentVariables
`[[X,5], [Y,10]]`.**

Comment: How does this differ from [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661309/dcg-prolog-testing-several-sentences)? My answer, which you accepted, shows you exactly how to get `[X=5, Y=10]`.

Comment: I just figured that out. I will edit it to ask a more advanced part.